# How to display emojis in meta description

Tags: php, html, wordpress, meta, yoast

I send my sitemap generated by Yoast SEO to Google but somehow, the SEO was sent wrong.

Here is an example of what I send: http://prntscr.com/rqmn9l

Here is what came out in Google: http://prntscr.com/rqmqfw

How can I fix the inconsistencies?

Answer (score 0):

Your question title is not clear and should be "how to display emojis in meta description"

And the answer is you must use the html code of the emoji instead of the emoji itself in your meta description.

So instead of:

```
<meta name="description" content="My awesome description">
```

You shoul use:

```
<meta name="description" content="My awesome description &#128512;">
```

Comment: That's not my question tho. The problem is that it didn't even take the meta that I created.

Comment: Google often grab text from your page to display instead of the meta description if it finds it more relevant for the query asked. If you really intend to use emojis in your description, try my solution if not try removing them because they could be seen as a bug for bots, so less relevant for Google.